# Unable to convert List<List<int>> to return type IList<IList<int>>

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, generic-collections

For level order traversal why does this exception occur?
Following exception occurs:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```cs
public IList<IList<int>> LevelOrder(TreeNode root) 
{
    var result = new List<List<int>>();
    var que = new Queue<TreeNode>();

    //if(root==null) return result;

    que.Enqueue(root);
    while(que.Count!=0)
    {
        int n = que.Count;
        var subList = new List<int>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(que.Peek().left!=null) 
                que.Enqueue(que.Peek().left);
            if(que.Peek().right!=null)
                que.Enqueue(que.Peek().right);
            subList.Add(que.Dequeue().val);
        }
        result.Add(subList);
    }
    return  result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `return result as IList<IList<int>>` ? Or specifying the type of result explicitly, i.e. `IList<IList<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();`?

Comment: A `List` is an `IList` and can safely be treated as either.  A `List<List>` and `List<IList>` *cannot* because if anything is added to the List which is *not* a `List`, it breaks any code treating it as `List<List>` (it becomes no longer a `List<List>`).  That's the basic issue.  `Covariance` and `Contravariance`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just change the declaration of your result to `List<IList<int>>`.

`List<T>` implements `IList<T>`, but `List<List<T>>`  does not implement `IList<IList<int>>`.  Generic parameters are not covariant or contravariant unless defined that way and `IList<T>` is not, so the type must match exactly.

```
public IList<IList<int>> LevelOrder(TreeNode root)
{
    var result = new List<IList<int>>();
    var que = new Queue<TreeNode>();

    //if(root==null) return result;

    que.Enqueue(root);
    while (que.Count != 0)
    {
        int n = que.Count;
        var subList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (que.Peek().left != null)
                que.Enqueue(que.Peek().left);
            if (que.Peek().right != null)
                que.Enqueue(que.Peek().right);
            subList.Add(que.Dequeue().val);
        }
        result.Add(subList);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that if it compiles, doing a cast is a real bad idea.  Here's why:

```
public class myStupidList : IList<int>
{
//implementation unimportant
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var result = new List<List<int>>();
  IList<IList<int>> imNotAListofLists = (IList<IList<int>>)result;
  imNotAListofLists.Add(new myStupidList());
  //result is not a very valid variable right now, is it?
}
```

As mentioned in my comment, these types of collection issues boil down to `covariance` and `contravariance`, and .NET does provide a lot of tools for dealing with them.  (Such as various read-only collections and interfaces)

..Which, explains why you get your error as well.  There is no implicit cast from `List<List>` to `List<IList>` because that cast cannot succeed without breaking type-safety.  (and as @Grax mentioned, neither derives from the other)

Answer (score 0):

There should be explicit conversion and as shown below:-

`List<IList<int>> result = new List<IList<int>>();`

or

`var result = new List<IList<int>>();`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.